# While loop not terminating C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while, stdvector

I would like to keep inputting integers to the P1 vector until a break point in this case 'q' or 'Q' is entered. The program when ran goes crazy into an endless loop once the break condition is met. Any ideas on a work around, all I can see is that because the 'q' or 'Q' is a character the integer vector is taking this as an input when the while loop runs at which point it endless loops?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaring Polynomial 1 and 2
    vector<int> P1;
    vector<int> P2;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (x != 'q'||x != 'Q') {
        cout << "Please enter in the first polynomial one value at a time (Press Q when done)...";
        cin >> x;
        P1.push_back(x);
    }

    //Also tested with a do while same problem
  /*do
    {
    cout << "Please enter in the first polynomial one value at a time (Press Q when done)...";
    cin >> x;

    P1.push_back(x);

    } while (x != 'q');*/



    //Ignore this is for next part of program
    vector<int> Res((P1.size() + P2.size()) + 1);

    cout << P1.size() << "," << P2.size() << "," << Res.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The condition `x != 'q'||x != 'Q'` is always true. Do you see why?

Comment: Well x starts as 0 which is not q so it starts as TRUE so my logic is that false or false =false so will keep running until x becomes 'q' or 'Q' which is when it become FALSE and breaks out of the loop surely?

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense to compare an integer variable with a character literal? Try this code: `int x = 'Q'; cout << x;` What does it print? Is this what you want or expect?

Answer (score 2):

(x != 'q'||x != 'Q') <---- here is an error, it is obviously always true: when x==q -> true, because (x! = 'Q') == true, and the other way around. change || to &&.

Comment: changed || to && Still gives me an endless loop

Comment: try clean & compile again?

Comment: It doesn't like (x != 'q' && x != 'Q') sends the program into a endless loop

Comment: Changing the `||` operator to `&&` in this case makes no difference. The condition will still evaluate to `true` because the variable is of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The condition:

```
(x != 'q' || x != 'Q')
```

is always `true` resulting in an endless loop. Why that is in more details:

The `x` integer variable is initialized to `0`. Then you check if `x` is different than `'q'` which represents an integer value of `111`. It is not equal to that value so the expression of `x != 'q'` is `true`. Then you check if `x` is not equal to `'Q'` character which represents an integer value of `85`. It is not equal to that value so the expression of `x != 'Q'` is also `true`. We end up with a condition of `(true || true)` which is always `true`.

Integral values are implicitly convertible to boolean values where `0` represents `false` and any other number represent `true`. Try something like this instead:

```
char c = 'y';
while (std::cin && (c == 'y' || c == 'Y')) {
    // do work
    std::cout << "Do you want to repeat the input? y / n?";
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

That being said you don't need the `"stdafx.h"` header.

Comment: ah I understand I have it so it starts as true and when x becomes false for one statment the other statement is still true and OR makes it still TRUE overall

Comment: I now do not understand why.... while (x != 'q' && x != 'Q') does not work? endless loop

Comment: Thankyou now it doesn't seem to exit when I press n

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Ron but I seem to be getting all sorts of errors now

Comment: I assume you removed the stdafx.h header. Unless you disable PCH (in your project settings) removing it will create a few compiler errors. If that is not the case you will have to edit your question to add the errors. Playing a game of guess what errors is not that useful..

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should not use `int x`
Second just like Ron said change `||` to `&&`
Anyway, Ron gave an example and it works.

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback I must say that you should post comments as comments, not as answers. In order to do that  please build some rep to be able to post comments.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You are right I do it in the future