# I don't exactly understand why my while loop is not catching any of these conditions

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, reverse

**I'm trying to output the input string in reverse and when the user inputs "done", "Done", or "d" it will stop. With this, the while loop does not catch any of these conditions to stop the loop.**

```
#include`<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   string userInput;
   int i;
   char output;
   getline(cin, userInput);

    
    
      while (userInput != "done" || userInput != "Done" || userInput != "d") {
        for (i = userInput.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            output = userInput.at(i);
            cout << output;
        }
        cout << endl;
        getline(cin, userInput);
    } 
   

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself - can condition `x != 1 || x != 2` ever be `false`?

Comment: Carefully (and I mean *carefully*) mentally evaluate the condition for userInput "Done".  (userInput != "done"), that's true.  So what next?  true OR false OR false equals what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ while loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221201/c-while-loop-not-working)

Comment: duplicates: [While loop not terminating C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46874309/995714), [How do I get multiple conditions within one while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402665/995714)

Comment: I bet this is a case where you believed that C++ works the same way we speak English.  When English speakers say "OR", it can mean "all", but that is not how boolean logic works.  An "OR" (`||`) has a special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
while (userInput != "done" || userInput != "Done" || userInput != "d")
```

with

```
while ( ! (userInput == "done" || userInput == "Done" || userInput == "d") )
```